What's the set of points on the unit circle when one removes all nth roots of unity as n goes to infinity?
I understand that the unit circle has many points that are not roots of unity.  Does this set of not-roots-of-unity correspond to any well known set / have any special properties? What are equivalent definitions of this set?

Irrational multiples of a rotation?

I think you can write them as $\exp(\alpha\pi i)$ where $\alpha$ is an irrational number.

Characterisation:
An $n$th root of unity is an element of the unit circle with argument equal to $2\pi\frac{k}{n}$ for $k$ an integer, modulo $2\pi$. If you let $n$ run over $\Bbb N$, you cover all elements of the unit circle with argument a rational multiple of $2\pi$. Our set is then the set of all elements of the circle with irrational argument.
An equivalent definition is: this set is the image of $[0,1)\setminus\Bbb Q$ under the canonical homeomorphism $[0,1)\cong\Bbb T_1$ (note: we are not using the usual topology on $[0,1)$ here).
Interesting properties:
This set has (arclength, Lebesgue) measure equal to the whole measure of $\Bbb T_1$. An interesting point about arbitrary elements $\zeta$ of this set is that the orbit: $$\{\zeta^n:n\in\Bbb N_0\}$$Is a dense subset of $\Bbb T_1$ (Kronecker's theorem), and moreover this orbit is uniformly recurrent, meaning:

For any $s\in\Bbb T_1$ and any neighbourhood $U$ of $s$, there are $M,N\in\Bbb N$ such that $\zeta^N\in U$ and for any $n\in\Bbb N$ with $\zeta^n\in U$, there is at least one $k\in\{n+1,\cdots,n+M\}$ such that $\zeta^k\in U$ also.

Intuitively this means the orbit $(\zeta^n)$ will visit any neighbourhood $U$ of any point $s$ both:

Infinitely many times
Regularly - there is some 'time step' $M$ such that you can guarantee the orbit visits $U$ again within $M$ 'steps'

The measure-preserving dynamical system $(\Bbb T_1,\lambda;\rho_\zeta)$ is an ergodic system for any such $\zeta$.
The sequence $\left(\frac{1}{2\pi}\arg(\zeta^n)\bmod2\pi\right)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is equidistributed in $[0,1)$. A remarkable corollary is that, for suitably nice functions $f:[0,1]\to\Bbb R$, we have: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nf\left(\frac{1}{2\pi}\arg(\zeta^k)\bmod2\pi\right)=\int_0^1f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$$
Which is, in my opinion, a very beautiful alternative to the usual Riemann sum. The notation can be cleaned by allowing $f:\Bbb T_1\to\Bbb C$: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nf(\zeta^k)=\oint_{\Bbb T_1}f\,\mathrm{d}\lambda$$
Where $\lambda$ is the normalised arclength measure (the Hausdorff-1 measure scaled down by $1/2\pi$). All of this can be found in Operator Theoretic Aspects of Ergodic Theory, Eisner, Nagle et. al.
